# How to CPU effectively add item to a list of unique items

Tags: algorithm, performance

*Preamble: This question should be language neutral, it's academic question regarding the algorithm, but for clarity and because it's my favorite language, I will write examples in C++.*

Imagine following simple structure:

```
struct Item
{
    char Char;
    std::string String;
};
```

Now, I have a list of these items, say `std::vector<Item> list`. What I want is to create a function that will allow me to add an item to this list, but skip, if the item is already in a list. So that it contains every item only once. The most simple implementation that comes to my mind is:

```
void AppendItem(Item item)
{
    // Check if the item is in the list and if yes, exit the function
    foreach (Item x, list)
    {
        // Compare char first, because comparing 2 chars is as CPU complex as comparing 2 numbers
        if (item.Char != x.Char)
            continue;
        // Now we can compare the strings, which is relatively complex operation
        if (item.String == x.String)
            return;
    }
    // There clearly isn't any such item in a list, so let's add it
    list.push_back(item);
}
```

So far it's looking as a stupid question, which it actually is. But now it becomes more interesting.

Imagine there is already 2000 items in a list and I want to add 1000 more. I don't know if any of these 1000 is already in list or not.

If I recursively use this dumb function, I result in looping over every item 2000 + N times (N being 0 - 999) * 1000. Which is very slow, given the  implementation of string comparison. Even on my i7 CPU it's slow.

Is there any smarter algorithm of how can I accomplish this? I might even sacrifice some RAM as long as it would eat less CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost each language has a list that is optimized for holding only unique values. In C++ you could use a [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) instead of a list. In C# you would use a [`HashSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx). In JavaScript you would use an object...

In your question you're doing a O(N) lookup for each element, a set or unique list will at least do a O(log(N)) which is many times faster.

Comment: Um, in fact I am not working with stdlibs at all. I just used them to express my problem in most common way. I am more interested in theoretical solution. Why is std::set more efficient? What does it do on background that it's better?

Comment: @Petr You use an efficient lookup algorithm to see if the value is in the set rather than scanning it.  Many options exist with different tradeoffs.  You can read up on hashes, BTrees, and so on if you want to learn more.

Comment: In C++11, `std::unordered_set` might be faster, because it is based on hash tables, so it takes *O(1)* on average, vs *O(log N)* worst case time for balanced search trees in `std::set`.

Answer (score -1):

So you are sure that those 1000 items you want to add are all unique among each other?

If so, then one possibility is to first check if an item would be added (is not already in the list) and then temporary save them in a separate list. Afterwards you concatenate both lists.

Another optimization would be to keep the list ordered in some way like in alphabetical order based on the string data member of the items. That way you can use searching methods like the binary search algorithm to speed up the process of checking for uniqueness.

Comment: No, as stated in my question: I don't know if any of these 1000 is already in list or not.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm sorry. Is the second part useful though?

Comment: I don't know, probably it might work, but that hash table lookup sounds more promising. Just FYI, I didn't downvote your answer, I still appreciate it, even if it doesn't really help me :)